# Nautilus sometimes refuses to rename files or folders - terminal works

Tags: nautilus, mv

I sometimes have the following issue:
I'm working with Nautilus (Ubuntu 14.10 with Unity) and for example create new folders. But when I want to rename them, I can select that in the context menu and also get into the edit mode (file name highlighted, text cursor there), but whatever key I hit, I am unable to change the name. There will be just always the same default name.

I could not find any specific causes for this problem, it seems to occur randomly, and also with other files or old folders. When it once started to refuse renaming items, it will stay in that state until the next reboot. But using the terminal `mv oldname newname` always works, it is specific to Nautilus and seems to have nothing to do with permissions.

Anyone else that had this problem? Do you know the cause or how to fix this?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Nemo answer deleted to attract more interesting solutiuons...

Comment: @Fabby Thank you, but could you undelete it at the end of the bounty period? It was not a too bad answer, so it should come back later. And if nothing better appears, I don't want to have the +50 wasted... :-)

Comment: Yes, Off course!   Because now, deleting it made me lose 10 rep (upvoted once) Next time: ask me to put in a bounty if my answer wasn't good enough...  ;-)

Comment: Did you already try removing `~/.config/nautilus`? Many times when GUI starts acting weird, local settings got the flu.

Comment: @JacobVlijm No, I didn't. Delete the folder or contents only? And that would reset all my Nuatilus settings to default, so I will have to set them again, I assume.

Comment: You can remove (or alternatively rename, to see if that is the cause) the whole folder. All settings will indeed be lost then.

Comment: Thank you. I will try it when the error occurs the next time.

Comment: Well, it should *prevent* the occurrence, once it occurs it won't help untill the next time, the possibly damaged preferences are loaded already then.

Comment: I think you are looking for an answer how to solve this with nautilus, but in my experience nautilus in ubuntu is absolutely broken for anything beside viewing folder contents. If you rely on a powerful Filenavigator, look for alternatives. I use Nemo with Unity Patches from webupd8 ppa. Just works.

Comment: Curious if you had any results with removing the settings folder :)

Comment: @JacobVlijm I just renamed it, as you said it could only prevent the error maybe, but it seems like the folder is only processed at boot, so I will have to wait until the next reboot for seeing the changes. Unfortunately, I can't reboot now, because my laptop has a buggy graphics card that only allows me to boot when it is completely cold. That would mean waiting half an hour or so... :(

Comment: WOW, I hope you don't need to reboot too often :)

Comment: I noticesd the same behavior when Using the connect to server mode. Works fine locally, but remotely, It would fail and not give a warning.

Comment: Which `nautilus --version`?

Comment: @Pandya `nautilus --version` gives output `GNOME nautilus 3.10.1`. It is the version that came with Ubuntu 14.10, but always updated.

Comment: @Fabby the bounty period is over, please restore your old answer. :-)

Comment: Done and upvoted the Question!  ;-)

Comment: Please show at least *some* courtesy and at least -for more than one reason- post the result of: removing the config files/log out/log in. Did you even try?

Comment: @JacobVlijm I _did_ try that, but I am not really sure whether it helped. My configuration was not changed at all after the reboot. The files I tried to rename worked, but as I said, it occurs randomly. It did not happen in the time (2 days) between I renamed the folder and I disabled Ibus as the answer below suggested.

Comment: The trick is to not touch (open) nautilus at all after removing the files, or better, remove them from another account (with sudo). Else the existing (loaded) settings will be simply rewritten.

Comment: Oh. That might have been the cause. Sorry for me being dumb >_< But kos' answer seems to have the issue solved anyway...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's probably due to a bug in `ibus`:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1385292

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1392600

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/1416607

Suggested workarounds are to set `Keyboard input method system` to `none` in System Settings > Language support > Language tab (permanent fix), to kill the `ibus` daemon with `sudo killall ibus-daemon` (session time fix) or to restart `nautilus` (temporary fix)

Comment: Restarting Nautilus (closing window and reopening) does not help. And what will happen if I kill the ibus-daemon? What is it responsible for? I mean if I could just kill or permanently disable it, why would it be used at all?

Comment: @ByteCommander That's because closing all windows and reopening one doesn't restart nautilus, `killall nautilus` and either clicking on the Files icon on the Unity Dash (suggested) or `nautilus` does. Killing `ibus` as well as permanently disable it as far as i know will drop the support it provides for the insertion of some non-latin characters. I'm not an expert of the matter, but if you use a non-latin keyboard layout you could just try to disable `ibus` from System Settings and check if the layout-specific character will still work afterwards

Comment: Standard German notebook keyboard. So I have to re-enable ibus if I get problems with special characters, okay. If that is all, I hope it won't affect me too much. I will try that! I just don't know whether it solved the issue, because it appears randomly. You know some more things about WHY/WHEN it happens? (To try to manually provoke it?)

Comment: @ByteCommander Well, that's unfortunate. No, it seems pretty random. Just test it enough to be sure that the issue it's gone. It seems like it helped a lot of users on launchpad tough

Comment: Okay. I will do some renamings then until the bounty expires... If it looks good, I will make you happy ;D

Comment: @ByteCommander Well, looking forward for that :)

Comment: After setting the keyboard input method system from "Ibus" to "none", I did not have any more problems until now. So I think you did your job well @kos, so here comes the promised reward! Thanks for you help! :-)

Comment: @ByteCommander Glad that it helped!

Comment: Removing iBus is THE solution after 3 years? Looks like industrial sabotage to hinder the development of non-English-speaking countries... Or at least to hinder the spread of free software philosophy...