# Nautilus suddenly closes when I attempt to drag a file or folder

Tags: unity, nautilus

I am not able to work with Nautilus as it is closing off its windows unexpectedly. Is there any fix for this. I have run `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` and my system is up to date.

once the nautilus closes, the files on the desktop is not visible at all. Needs a reboot to get it back.

Adding dmesg

```
[   56.375497] nautilus[2242]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff1476f5f8 error 14 in nautilus[400000+152000]
[  752.485915] nautilus[7310]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fffcd247cf8 error 14 in nautilus[400000+152000]
```

Please help

**Update**

Its just not nautilus. its even nemo. dmesg below.

```
[  672.597851] nemo[7177]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff8cac9be8 error 14 in nemo[400000+16f000]
[  733.646608] nemo[7285]: segfault at 0 ip           (null) sp 00007fff9c2636b8 error 14 in nemo[400000+16f000]
```

Also bittorrent client as well.

Comment: Why is this voted down? What is wrong in here? Please add comments if you need more info. Even google did not help me in here.

Comment: I can't tell you why your issue happens or how to fix it, but I also have problems with Nautilus. It seems like there are some serious bugs in it, but I don't know either. The only thing I can suggest you at the moment is to use Nemo instead of Nautilus. See the answer of @Fabby to my question there if you want to give it a try: http://askubuntu.com/questions/579701/nautilus-sometimes-refuses-to-rename-files-or-folders-terminal-works

Comment: run nautilus from the terminal. perhaps you'll see the specific error after it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing worked. Hence I had to go for a fresh install.

Answer (score 0):

Are you, by any chance, using custom themes? I had some serious problems with those, but I don't know exactly what was causing them.

*Nemo* is used in *Linux Mint*, which is based on *Ubuntu*. Although there is no answer for your problem (if it were for Windows, I would suppose it had something to do with your custom themes), changing to *Nemo* might prevent the crashing, for the time being.

Comment: Even Nemo is having the same issue.

Comment: I tried to remove all the themes. but of no use. It is still giving me the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The dmesg shows that there is a segmentation fault. This can also happen because of bad memory sector.

Try installing [Memtest](http://www.memtest.org/) and check your memory first.